# preg_replace replace only once even if the match is found

Tags: php, preg-replace

my HTML form code replaces some words with <-#word#-> using the code

```
$string = preg_replace("/($p)/i", '<-#$1#->', $string);
```

the problem is that if the form has some errors, upon resubmitting the form the word becomes <-#<-#<-#word#->#->#-> every time someone resubmits the form. Is it possible to replace but if it is already replaced then do not.
This is what I tried using NOT operator but it is not working

```
$string = preg_replace("/^(<-#)($p)^(#->)/i", '<-#$1#->', $string);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negative [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert what is directly on the left an on the right is not `<-#` and

```
(?<!<-#)(word)(?!#->)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OIBFLs/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/4qssk)

Your code could look like:

```
$string = preg_replace("/(?<!<-#)($p)(?!#->)/i", '<-#$1#->', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method might be to check with `preg_match_all()` to ensure if your matches are returning:

```
$string = '<-#<-#<-#Any alphanumeric input that user may wish#->#->#->';
preg_match_all("/(<-#)+([A-Za-z0-9_\s]+)(#->)+/s", $string, $matches);

$string = '<-#' . $matches[2][0] . '#->';
var_dump($string);
```

which outputs:

```
string(47) "<-#Any alphanumeric input that user may wish#->"
```

`var_dump($matches);` would return:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(59) "<-#<-#<-#Any alphanumeric input that user may wish#->#->#->"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "<-#"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "Any alphanumeric input that user may wish"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "#->"
  }
}
```